# Drag and drop between TreeView and Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a grid with two columns on it. In the left column is a TreeView and on the right column there's a TextBox. Now I want to be able to drag an item from the TreeView to the TextBox and the header of the selected TreeViewItem should be appenden to the text. I searched a lot for "drag and drop between controls" in the web, but all this things don't work for me.

My actual code is:

```
private Point startPoint;

    private void tvPreviewLeftMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
    }

    private void tvPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
            return;

        Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
        Vector diff = startPoint - mousePos;
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
            Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
            Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
        {
            TreeView treeView = sender as TreeView;
            TreeViewItem treeViewItem = FindAnchestor<TreeViewItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
            object val = treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(treeViewItem);
            DataObject dragData = new DataObject("myFormat", treeViewItem.Header);
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(treeViewItem, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }

    private static T FindAnchestor<T>(DependencyObject current)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        do
        {
            if (current is T)
                return (T) current;
            current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        } while (current != null);
        return null;
    }

    private void frtbDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat"))
        {
            var val = (string) e.Data.GetData("myFormat");
        }
    }

    private void frtbDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat") || sender == e.Source)
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
```

The according XAML is:

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TreeView Grid.Column="0" x:Name="treeview" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="tvPreviewLeftMouseDown" PreviewMouseMove="tvPreviewMouseMove"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" AllowDrop="True" Drop="frtbDrop" DragEnter="frtbDragEnter"/>
</Grid>
```

If I debug it the method *tvPreviewMouseMove* works fine. The DataObject is created and gets the correct value. But the drop- and dragenter-events are never fired. What's wrong here?

Comment: I changed "myFormat" to DataFormats.Text and now it works, but the eventhandlers for drop and dragenter are not invoked. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was that I had subscribed for the DragEnter- and Drop-Event. I changed them to PreviewDragEnter and PreviewDrop and now it works

Answer (score 0):

```
private void frtbDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if(!e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat") || sender == e.Source)
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    else
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
}
```